# Ionic - Cannot find module 'Firebase'

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have followed the tutorial at https://www.djamware.com/post/5a629d9880aca7059c142976/build-ionic-3-angular-5-and-firebase-simple-chat-app to build an Ionic app using Firebase's realtime database.

It works perfectly locally via `ionic serve`. I have also used the Ionic DevApp and again, it works perfectly.

I have now pushed my code to Ionic but during the build I get this error and the build process terminates:

```
[11:20:31]  typescript: src/pages/chat/chat.ts, line: 7 
            Cannot find module 'Firebase'. 

       L7:  import * as firebase from 'Firebase';

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
    at Promise ()
    at transpileWorker (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:109:82
    at 
npm info lifecycle fanslide@0.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
```

In `chat.ts` I have:

```
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';
```

Inside `package.json` I can see:

```
"firebase": "^4.8.0",
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong and why this works locally but not when the build takes place on Ionic's server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this issue and successfully complete a build in Ionic by changing:

```
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';
```

To:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```